# How to pause the clock when app is going in the background state

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I created a progress bar using `react-native-reanimated` and `react-native-redash` that is working fine but now I want to pause the progress or clock when the app is going to the background state and when the app comes to the active state it should be resume with the last position and the time.

`clock config`

```
const runTiming = (clock, quizDurationTiming) => {
  const state = {
    finished: new Value(0),
    position: new Value(0),
    frameTime: new Value(0),
    time: new Value(0),
  }
  const config = {
    toValue: new Value(1),
    duration: quizDurationTiming * 10,
    easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease),
  }

  return block([
    cond(
      not(clockRunning(clock)),
      set(state.time, 0),
      timing(clock, state, config)
    ),
    cond(eq(state.finished, 1), stopClock(clock)),

    state.position,
  ])
}

const SpecialTestTimer = ({
  preparationTime,
  appState,
  quizDurationTiming,
}) => {
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false)
  const clock = useClock()
  const progress = useValue(0)
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(true)
  const isProgress = useValue(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (appState == "active") setPlay(true)
    else setPlay(false)
  }, [appState])

  useCode(() => set(isProgress, play ? 1 : 0), [play])

  useCode(
    () => [
      cond(and(progress, not(clockRunning(clock))), startClock(clock)),
      cond(and(not(progress), clockRunning(clock)), stopClock(clock)),

      set(progress, runTiming(clock, quizDurationTiming)),
    ],
    []
  )
}
```

I wrote this code but not working properly like which I want. when I go to the screen `clock` is not starting but when I came to the app after the `background` state then the `clock` is starting.

Comment: Please refer to App State doc here https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate. You can attach listeners and start/stop your clock accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I already attached a listener in the `parent` component

Comment: So what's your problem ?

Comment: @BloodyMonkey  the problem is that the `clock` is not stopping at the first time when the app is going to the `background` state. mean when the app is going to the `background` state then comes in `active` state then again goes to `background` state then the `clock` is stopping.